# MKMapView strange crash when tracking location

Tags: uikit, mapkit, mkmapview

I have an UIViewController subclass and an IBOutlet named map to an MKMapView instance.
So far, so great, but sometimes the app crashes without a reason when the view controller triggers the `viewDidLoad` method. This is absolutely randomly, but only happens when I created around three instances and then create a new one and push it into a navigation controller (however, I have only one of these view controllers at the same time in the navigation controller stack!).

Here is the code of the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [map setDelegate:self];
    [map setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [map setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    if(area)
        self.area = area;
}
```

The stacktrace shows that it crashes when I call `[map setShowsUserLocation:YES];` but only on this line (when I comment it out, it never crashes). Here is the stacktrace:

[image]

(Sorry for the picture, but I was too lazy to type it all).

Does anyone knows what happens there an why it crashes?

Comment: Looks like it might be crashing when adding the annotation for your current position. Perhaps it would help to have the gist of any annotation-related code.

Comment: Ah, forget to add it, although I set the delegate, I don't watch for any event or implemented any delegate method. So everything is still on its default settings.

Comment: Are there multiple instances live at the same time? Or are they created and released at different times with only one alive at a time?

Comment: Only one is alive at a time, but the very first instance never crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `[map setShowsUserLocation:NO];` in your `viewDidUnload`. I have a similar situation, but I recreate the MKMapView programmatically every time the view reloads, and haven't seen this problem.

Comment: Great, this works like a charm (also setting it to NO in the dealloc method). Thanks for your help!